# Type '' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & '. Property '' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I new to frontend development with React/Redux/Typescript.

I am building a Todo App. I have the following error:

> Type '{ todo: Todo; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes
>   & Todo'.   Property 'todo' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes
>   & Todo'.  TS2322

I have tried search online but I cannot figure out why.

My code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo} from './index'

function AddToDo() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  function handleInput(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setInput(e.target.value)
  }

  //dispatch to store
  function handleAddTodo() {
    addTodo(input)
    setInput('')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)}/>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAddTodo}>
        Add todo
      </button>
    </div>
)
}

//connect
connect(null, { addTodo })(AddToDo)

//TodoList
interface Todo {
  id: number
  text: string
}

interface TodoState {
  todos: Todo[]
}

function TodoList(todos: Todo[]) {

  return (
    <ul className="todo-list">
      {todos.map((todo: Todo, index) => {
        //??
        return <Todo todo={todo} />;
        })
       }
    </ul>
  )
}

function mapStateToProps(state:TodoState) {
 // const { todos } = state
  return { TodoList}
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList)

//Todo
function Todo( todo:Todo ) {

  return (
    <li>
      {todo}
    </li>
  )
}

connect()(Todo)

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AddToDo />
      <TodoList />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does updating the function signature to ‘function Todo({todo}:{todo:Todo}) { ‘     Work for you?  Actually looks like you need to do the same on Todolist.  react components pass an object called props.  Todo or todos are keys on those props objects.

Comment: Solved. Do you have any recommendation on this topic? (Keywords for search are great)